# Matplotlib Deprecation Warning: specify the corners of the quadrilaterals with X and Y, or

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code to create colorized price charts, here's an example of the output:
[image: Colorized chart]

The code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot(ax: plt.Axes, df: pd.DataFrame, points: pd.Series, booleans: pd.Series, c1: list, c2: list):
    ncols = len(booleans)
    s = booleans.astype(object).replace({False: 0, True: 1})
    z = np.array(s).reshape(1, ncols)
    x = np.array(df.index)
    y = [points.min(), points.max()]
    N = 256
    vals = np.ones((N, 4))
    vals[:, 0] = np.linspace(c1[0], c2[0], N)
    vals[:, 1] = np.linspace(c1[1], c2[1], N)
    vals[:, 2] = np.linspace(c1[2], c2[2], N)
    newcmp = ListedColormap(vals)
    plt.rcParams['pcolor.shading'] = 'auto'
    ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, alpha=0.2, cmap=newcmp)
    return ax
```

Full-disclosure, I don't understand how colormaps work in matplotlib, this code is slightly modified from another SO question.

The following error prints whenever I run this code, and nothing I've tried seems to fix the issue.

**NOTE: The error does disappear after I try different solutions and I use importlib.reload() to reload the function in my jupyter notebook, but it always comes back later.**

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: shading='flat' when X and Y have the
> same dimensions as C is deprecated since 3.3.  Either specify the
> corners of the quadrilaterals with X and Y, or pass shading='auto',
> 'nearest' or 'gouraud', or set rcParams['pcolor.shading'].  This will
> become an error two minor releases later.

Comment: You could try to set `z = np.array(s)[:-1].reshape(1, ncols)` so it has one entry less than `x`. In a colormesh, `x` and `y` indicate the cell borders and `z` the cell contents. There is one cell less in each dimension than there are borders. By the way, if you write *"this code is slightly modified from another SO question."*, it would be helpful (and kind to the original author) to provide a link.  Probably that other question contains some hints.

Comment: My memory was wrong, it was from this page, about half-way down, where it says "Of course we need not start from a named colormap":
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html

Comment: I tried adding the [:-1] before reshape, and it throws the error "cannot reshape array of size 4343 into shape (1, 4344)". I guess it's trying to add an element and can't arbitrarily increase the array length.

Comment: `z = np.array(s)[:-1].reshape(1, ncols-1)` or even simpler `z = np.array(s)[:-1].reshape(1, -1)`.  The idea isn't to increase the array length, but to decrease it, as it is one element too large.

Comment: Yup! That's the fix: `np.array(s)[:-1].reshape(1, -1)`. Want to submit an answer? I'll hit accept. Thank you!

Comment: The principal problem is that your array of `booleans` should be one less than the index of the dataframe.  You are basically coloring line segments, and there is always one segment less than there are points. So, the error is in how you are calling this function (and in the way the array `booleans` is created). Also note that your colormap only needs two colors; you can simplify it as `newcmp = ListedColormap([c1,c2])` without needing `vals`.

Comment: Another great point, thanks! But do you want to submit an answer so you get the credit for the answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit hard to answer, as information is missing about how the array `booleans` is created and its meaning.

Supposing the `booleans` indicate some property of the line segments, it needs to be 1 shorter than the number of points (). You can use the default `'flat'` shading (one flat color per cell in the mesh).  In the code example below, the very last value in `df['is ascending']` is dummy and can be removed for the colormesh.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot(ax: plt.Axes, df: pd.DataFrame, points: pd.Series, booleans: pd.Series, c1: list, c2: list):
     s = booleans
     if len(s) == len(df):
          s = s[:-1]  # s needs to be one less than the number of values in the index
     z = np.array(s).reshape(1, -1)
     x = np.array(df.index)
     y = [points.min(), points.max()]
     N = 256
     newcmp = ListedColormap([c1, c2])
     ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, alpha=0.2, cmap=newcmp, shading='flat')

N = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.normal(1, 10, N).cumsum() + 1000},
                  index=pd.date_range('20220101', periods=N, freq='D'))
df['is ascending'] = df['val'] > df['val'].shift(-1)

ax = df['val'].plot()
plot(ax, df, df['val'], df['is ascending'], 'limegreen', 'crimson')
```

[image: colormesh indicating a segment property]

If, on the other hand, `booleans` is a property of the points, a mesh with two rows and exactly the same number of columns as the number of points can be used.  In that case, a `'gouraud'` shading will take care of coloring per vertex.

```py
def plot(ax: plt.Axes, df: pd.DataFrame, points: pd.Series, booleans: pd.Series, c1: list, c2: list):
     s = booleans
     z = np.tile(np.array(s), (2, 1))
     x = np.array(df.index)
     y = [points.min(), points.max()]
     N = 256
     newcmp = ListedColormap([c1, c2])
     ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap=newcmp, shading='gouraud')

N = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.normal(1, 10, N).cumsum() + 1000},
                  index=pd.date_range('20220101', periods=N, freq='D'))
df['is larger than mean'] = df['val'] > df['val'].mean()

ax = df['val'].plot()
plot(ax, df, df['val'], df['is larger than mean'], 'lightgreen', 'lightcoral')
```

[image: coloring per point]

Comment: Booleans is a column in the dataframe that contains boolean values which I want to use to determine the background color. It's pre-generated from the curve. This is the line of code that fixed it for me: `z = np.array(s)[:-1].reshape(1, -1)`

Comment: Well, it is still not clear whether `booleans` would refer to line segments or to points. When referring to segments, it is import to know whether either the last or the first value needs to be discarded.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I intended them to relate to the line segment, not the points. Thanks for pointing this out.